# C# - Check if JSON structure changed

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newstonsoft.JSON to work with JSON files I get from Internet, but the files often change structure and I don't want to check every day if it wasn't changed. How can I check if structure was changed? I don't care about values or about number of elements in array (but I care about structure of children). How can I achieve this?

```
{
"abc": true, // I want to check if there is "abc", but I don't care if it is true or false
"def": 4, // I want to check if there is "def", but I don't care which value it has
[
    {
    "ghi": false // I want to check if all the children has ghi,but I don't check the value
    }
] // I don't care if there is 1 or 1000 elements in array

}
```

Comment: `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` and deserialize will return null if it's not there.

Comment: @IanMercer Thanks! And how can I check if there are added new ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a JSON schema and validate JSON files against that schema using **JSON.Net**, something like that:

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(jsonSchema);
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
bool valid = obj.IsValid(schema);
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) and [here](http://json-schema.org/).

Alternatively, if you want just to check if a JSON you receive has all the properties as corresponding DTO class, you can mark all properties with `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attribute:

```
class Person
{
   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to detect if JSON has some extra properties compared to DTO you can do something like that:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Does it ignore different array element count? And works it both when something was removed and when something was added?